# Add attributes to Python module at runtime to be imported later

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-principal

I'm adding attributes to a module at runtime using the following inside a loop:

```
this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
setattr(this_module, attr_name, attr_value)
```

When I call `print dir(this_module)` from the module, it shows the attributes. Great!

When I import the module and try to use the attribute in a decorator, an `AttributeError` exception keeps getting thrown. To debug, I called `dir()` on the imported module and none of the attributes added on the fly are listed!

I even added the attribute names to `__all__` for the `import *` and still nothing!

Any ideas would be great. Also, please let me know of any terminology I could be missing. I wasn't able to find an answer searching Google.

--

Per a suggestion by Kevin, I added a dictionary to my Flask application (instead of his suggestion of top-level, just for ease of testing) and added those attributes to it:

```
app.security = dict()
```

In the loop:

```
app.security[attr_name] = attr_value
```

In the module where the decorator is used ('time_entry' is an attribute name and it holds a class instance):

```
@app.security['time_entry'].need()
```

When I try to start the server, I now get this error:

```
    @security["time_write"].require()
             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of just using a top-level dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure that the decorator is called _after_ the attribute has been set? Also you could try doing `global attr_name` followed by `attr_name = attr_value`.

Comment: @Kevin: Can't use a dictionary as a decorator, though, right? I have to be able to call it in a decorator.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: The attribute names and values are created on the fly from a database. I don't think it'd work in this situation.

Comment: You can't use a module as a decorator either.  A decorator can equally well access a dictionary or a module.

Comment: @Kevin: I tried. It said the opening brace was invalid syntax. Unless I'm missing a proper was of calling it.

Comment: You're going to need to show us your code if you want us to help you.  And why are you trying to "call" a dictionary?  Dictionaries (and modules) are not callable objects.  Functions are callable.  Methods are callable.  Classes are (basically) callable.

Comment: @Kevin: Sorry, I meant just using it in a decorator... The line (as it stands now) is `@security['time_write'].require()`. As far as I know, syntactically, there's nothing wrong with using a dictionary in a decorator.

Comment: @Logan: The decorator syntax consists of a [dotted name, possibly called as a function](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-decorator) (**edit**: [Guido on this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-August/046711.html)).  But you can just do `require = security['time_write'].require` on the line before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a *workaround* for my particular problem. It's not a solution and I still plan on investigating it further once this project is finished.

I created a dummy class and then set an attribute with an instance of it in my Flask application.

```
class Security: pass
app.security = Security()
```

Then, I set the attributes directly to the Security class:

```
setattr(app.security, attr_name, attr_value)
```

Again, it doesn't resolve why those module-level attributes I was creating at runtime weren't being imported. I'll come back and edit this once I have the answer to that question.